# Signing an app with system key

Tags: android

On Android 4.3 I'm trying to execute a system command (specifically wm) this way:

```
        String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "wm display 800x600", };
```

(...)

```
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

(...)

I get

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Must hold permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Although I compiled the app with the correct android permission.
I read somewhere that I can sign the apk with the system key, but... where to find it? How do I do it? And what's the fallback of that choice?

And, of course, would that fix my issue?

Thank you.

Comment: are you root on your device ?

Comment: Of course I don't know, this app is not for me, is for the market. Is it necessary?

Comment: if it is for the market, the answer is globally no, and therefore, you cannot have the proper key, as it is a private information kept by the person who compiles the platform.

Answer (score 3):

> where to find it?

You defined it yourself, when you built and signed your custom firmware for your ROM mod.

If you are not creating a ROM mod, then you do not have the firmware signing key and cannot use it.

> And, of course, would that fix my issue?

Presumably. It would be simpler to have your app be installed on the system partition by a rooted user, which should also allow you to hold `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`.

Comment: If the user rooted the phone, then what should I do to have my app be installed on the system partition? Is declaring android:installLocation="internalOnly" enough?

Comment: @Beppi's: "then what should I do to have my app be installed on the system partition?" -- that's outside the scope of StackOverflow. You should be able to find solutions on the Internet via a search engine, such as conducting a search for `android install app on system partition`. "Is declaring android:installLocation="internalOnly" enough?" -- no.

Comment: Unfortunately there are lots of guides on the user's side, it would be interesting if installing an app on a system partition could be performed by the app itself.